# Does the legend limit the number of titles?

Tags: swift, ios-charts

I am using iso-charts to try and draw a pie chart in an iOS app.

No matter what I try, I can't seem to get the full number of titles to draw in the legend.

I have my data set up as:

```
ages = ["18-", "25-", "35-", "45-", "55-", "65-", "75+"]
agePercentages = [10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 5.0, 10.0, 45.0, 120.0]
```

My code to setup the pieChart as:

```
func setPieDefaults(myPieChart: PieChartView) -> PieChartView {

    myPieChart.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width*0.5)
    myPieChart.usePercentValuesEnabled = true
    myPieChart.holeTransparent = true
    myPieChart.holeColor = UIColor.darkPurpleColor()
    myPieChart.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkPurpleColor()
    myPieChart.rotationAngle = 0.0
    myPieChart.rotationEnabled = true
    myPieChart.centerTextFont = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size:20)!
    myPieChart.descriptionText = ""
    myPieChart.centerText = "%"
    myPieChart.centerTextColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    myPieChart.drawHoleEnabled = true
    myPieChart.noDataText = "Loading Data ..."
    let legend = myPieChart.legend
    legend.font = UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 11)!
    legend.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    legend.position = .RightOfChart
    legend.form = .Circle

    return myPieChart
}
```

And ..

```
func setChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [Double], myPieView: PieChartView) {

    var dataEntries: [ChartDataEntry] = []

    for i in 0..<dataPoints.count {
        let dataEntry = ChartDataEntry(value: values[i], xIndex: i)
        dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
    }

    var colors = [UIColor]()
    switch myPieView {
    case genderPieChartView:
        colors = [UIColor.blueColor(), UIColor.pinkColor()]
    default:
        colors = ChartColorTemplates.colorful()
    }

    let pieChartDataSet = PieChartDataSet(yVals: dataEntries, label: nil)
    pieChartDataSet.sliceSpace = 3.0
    pieChartDataSet.colors = colors

    let pieChartData = PieChartData(xVals: dataPoints, dataSet: pieChartDataSet)
    myPieView.animate(xAxisDuration: 2, yAxisDuration: 2)

    let pFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    pFormatter.numberStyle = .PercentStyle
    pFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0
    pFormatter.percentSymbol = ""
    pFormatter.multiplier = 1
    pieChartData.setValueFormatter(pFormatter)
    pieChartData.setValueFont(UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Bold", size: 11)!)
    pieChartData.setValueTextColor(UIColor.whiteColor())

    myPieView.data = pieChartData
    myPieView.drawSliceTextEnabled = false

}
```

But it won't print any more than 5 of the labels. It's returning the pie-slices perfectly. But not the labels in the legend.

[image]

Am I doing something wrong? Thanks in advance for letting me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.

In reading the [framework docs](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/wiki/Legend) for the Android version a little better:

> The number of entries the automatically generated legend contains
>   depends on the number of different colors (across all DataSet objects)
>   as well as on the DataSet labels. The labels of the Legend depend on
>   the labels set for the used DataSet objects in the chart. If no labels
>   for the DataSet objects have been specified, the chart will
>   automatically generate them. If multiple colors are used for one
>   DataSet, those colors are grouped and only described by one label.

I realised I needed to increase the number of colours in the ChartColorTemplate.colorful() definition to match the number of labels I was trying to use. The current example code comes with only 5 colours defined.

```
public class func colorful () -> [UIColor]
{
    return [
        UIColor(red: 193/255.0, green: 37/255.0, blue: 82/255.0, alpha: 1.0),
        UIColor(red: 255/255.0, green: 102/255.0, blue: 0/255.0, alpha: 1.0),
        UIColor(red: 245/255.0, green: 199/255.0, blue: 0/255.0, alpha: 1.0),
        UIColor(red: 106/255.0, green: 150/255.0, blue: 31/255.0, alpha: 1.0),
        UIColor(red: 179/255.0, green: 100/255.0, blue: 53/255.0, alpha: 1.0),
        UIColor(red: 200/255.0, green: 100/255.0, blue: 53/255.0, alpha: 1.0), // added colour
        UIColor(red: 150/255.0, green: 150/255.0, blue: 70/255.0, alpha: 1.0), // added colour
        UIColor(red: 84/255.0, green: 78/255.0, blue: 53/255.0, alpha: 1.0), // added colour
    ]
}
```

If you have the same problem, then define a lot more colours to meet the needs of the maximum number of labels needed. This will also solve a problem if you try and word-wrap the legend (which I was also facing).